# Converts a text string into an array based on certain characters and symbols

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
let str  = "log(5)+sin(5)*π-cos(5)/√(4)*4^2";
```

I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
var newArr = ["log(", "5", ")", "+", "sin(", "5", ")", "*", "π", "-", "cos(", "5", ")", "/", "√(", "4", ")", "*", "4", "^", "2"];
```

I tried to use Split, but I did not get the result I wanted

```
str.split(/(\b)/g)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by Regex:

```js
let regex = /[A-Za-z√(]+|\d+|[)]|[+-/*^]|[π]/gm;
let str = `log(5)+sin(5)*π-cos(5)/√(4)*4^2`;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wtg3fl/1